# How to update the Message tag of an Iconic tile in WP8 from C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

When defining an Iconic tile in the WMAppManifest.xml file...

```
<TemplateIconic>
  <SmallImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\Tiles\IconicTileSmallTILT.png</SmallImageURI>
  <Count>0</Count>
  <IconImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\Tiles\IconicTileMediumLargeTILT.png</IconImageURI>
  <Title>MobileVaults</Title>
  <Message>A message</Message>
  <BackgroundColor>#A6CE39</BackgroundColor>
  <HasLarge>True</HasLarge>
  <LargeContent1></LargeContent1>
  <LargeContent2>No threats</LargeContent2>
  <LargeContent3>
  </LargeContent3>
  <DeviceLockImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\LockIconTILT.png</DeviceLockImageURI>
</TemplateIconic>
```

The Message tag appears in the upper right corner of the medium and large tiles.

Does anyone know how to update the Message value from C#. The IconicTileData class appears to mirror everything shown in the xml except for the Message.

Thanks for sharing the secret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to update the Message after the fact using the IconicTileData via XML or C#.  The following link provides all the information available for updating Iconic Tiles   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207009(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks. Not what I wanted hear.